# How do templating engines in JavaScript work?

Tags: javascript

Could you please explain me, how do templating engines in JavaScript work? Thank you.

**JSON**

```
{ "color" : "red"}
```

**Template**

```
<strong><%=color%></strong>
```

**Result**

```
<strong>Red</strong>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you provide more context?

Comment: I think that in general the approach for making a template engine is to select the appropriate algorithms and implement them using best-practice techniques to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 9):

As a starting point I would recommend you to give a look to the `String.prototype.replace` method and specially using its callback function:

```
function replaceTokens(str, replacement) {
  return str.replace(/<\%=([^%>]+)\%>/g, function (str, match) {
    return replacement[match];
  });
}

var input = "<strong><%=color%></strong>";
replaceTokens(input, { "color" : "Red"}); 
// returns <strong>Red</strong>

replaceTokens("<%=var1%> <%=var2%>", { "var1" : "Hello", "var2": "world!"});
// returns "Hello world!"
```

Give a look to these articles:

- [Search and Don't Replace](http://ejohn.org/blog/search-and-dont-replace/)
- [John Resig's Micro-Templating Engine](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/)
- [Better JavaScript Templates](http://blog.markturansky.com/BetterJavascriptTemplates.html) (JSP-like syntax)
- [jQuery Templates Proposal](http://wiki.github.com/nje/jquery/jquery-templates-proposal)

Comment: John Resing is best variant

Answer (score 2):

They may vary by implementation, but the one you're talking about looks like it works by doing the following:

1. Parse the page looking for keys in `<%= %>` tags
2. Match the key to the key/value pair in the JSON
3. Replace the tags/key with the value.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very different from other templating solutions (at the conceptual level).

```
{ "color" : "red"}
```

Specifies a `color` attribute with the value `red`.

```
<strong><%=color%></strong>
```

Means "Use the value of `color` wherever I have `<%=color%>`. Based on wahat you have, the templating-engine probably walks the DOM and finds nodes that have values that match `<%=somestring%>`. Then, it checks to see if there is an attribute that matches the `somestring` value. If there is one, it replaces the value of `<%=somestring%>` with the value defined in the JSON (which, in this case is `red`).

This finally gives you:

```
<strong>Red</strong>
```