# What is a template engine?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript templating engines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753971/javascript-templating-engines)

I keep on stumbling upon javascript templating engines and I have no idea what is their purpose. Could anyone explain me like I were five what are those? Can front-end developer make use of these?

Comment: JS template engines are for doing what should have been done on the server side.  If you're using them, either you're running node.js and *are* doing it server-side, or you're developing a huge ajax application you don't ever intend to show up in search engines.

Comment: mootools,scriptaculous,yui,jquery,dojo

Comment: Those aren't template engines...those are frameworks.

Comment: @cHao I generally agree with you, but there are some applications that make good use of them, for example in-house applications or applications where user experience > seo. Another example is http://www.documentcloud.org/home

Comment: Templating approaches are meant to simplify reuse of markup (in the world of the web). Although @cHao seems to imply their use only belongs on the server except for large-scale web apps, like any tool, when used properly, templates may be used effectively in most contexts in one way or another. For instance, a live Twitter roll, or when you find yourself using the same bit of [markup in Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/RTUd2/) over and over again.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

JavaScript template engines are often used when writing thick JS-clients or as "normal" template engines when using server-side js like Node.js.

Instead of cluttering the code by generating HTML using string concatenating etc., you instead use a template and interpolate the variable in them.

For instance in the example bellow you pass in an array `foo` to the template engine which then interpolates (replaces the placeholder ${data}) with item *i* from the array foo:

```
//pseudo code
<table>
 <tr>
   for each variable data in foo
    <td>${data}</td>
   end
 <tr>
</table>
```

In frameworks like backbone.js you typically use a template to implement the view part of the MVC pattern.

There are many different types of template engines in JS. Some are direct ports of server-side frameworks like ERB, HAML etc. Others are developed specially to work with JavaScript i.e [Pure](http://beebole.com/pure/)

There is a debate of how much expressiveness the template engine should give you because putting logic in your templates is usually a bad thing. Because of this some template engines are specifically designed to not let you put logic in them i.e [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)