# mechanics and meaning of JavaScript library syntax: ${ value }

Tags: javascript, templates

I've come across the following JavaScript code snippet in O'Reilly's 
JavaScript Web Applications:

```
// helper.js
var helper = {};
helper.formatDate = function(){ /* ... */ };

// template.html
<div>
  ${ helper.formatDate(this.date) }
</div>
```

However no reference to any particular JavaScript library is provided here.
What is the likely meaning of the ${ ... } syntax and how does it work?
Does this come from the use of any particular library? I've seen
jQuery's $() notation where $ is a function but I've not seen
$ followed by a curly bracket pair anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: It's just a placeholder in `template.html`.

Comment: Well, the puzzling thing is that once the function returns I expect to see something like ${2003-04-05} or something, which does not look like a variable name. How can a date value be a reasonable template variable name?

Answer (score 1):

It might be from the old, no longer in development [jQuery Tmpl library](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl) or some other template engine:

- [What is a template engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547028/what-is-a-template-engine)
- [JavaScript template engines](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/)

Comment: It might indeed be but is there a successor to the defunct jQuery Tmpl library which uses the same syntax etc... ?