# How to put placeholders for dynamic contents in html email?

Tags: html, css, laravel, html-email, laravel-blade

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4aozn05h/7/) (basically an html email) which I have replicated by following a particular design.

In the html email, there are some **dynamic contents in which I want to put placeholder** for time being as it will change for different customers.

The snippets of html code from the fiddle where I am using dynamic contents are:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="font-size:20px; padding-right: 23%;">
         <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">type:</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">availability check request</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">estimated total:</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">$250.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">what</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">Radio</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">how many</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">when:</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;word-wrap: break-word;
               width: 300px;">March 28/18 @ 7:00pm to March 30/18 @ 7:00pm</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">who:</td>
            <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;color:#FF8D58;">Mike</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </td>
</tr>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering how I can put a placeholder in the html code above where I am using dynamic contents such as `$250.00`, `Radio`, `2`, `March 28/18 @ 7:00pm to March 30/18 @ 7:00pm`

Comment: How are you populating the template? As in, where from/how is the data being provided to the template?

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson I will get back to you on this. At this moment, I am not sure. Is there any we can put the placeholder for now and change it according to the requirement later ?

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson I just figured out. We are populating the data from Laravel Blade which is itself a template.

Comment: I added a Laravel Blade example. This may not be perfectly accurate as I've never worked with Laravel before, but should help you get to your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One route you could take is to use a [template engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547028/what-is-a-template-engine). With this solution, you would replace each of the items that you want to replace with a common tag. In the example I included, this tag is just `{{...}}`.

Once you do this, you would provide your newly created template to the templating engine. The engine will then process your template by replacing each of the tags with the associated data.

```css
/* It was a little hard to read with all of the inline CSS */

table {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 23%;
}

table tr td {
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

table tr td:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}

table tr td:last-child {
  padding-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>type:</td>
    <td>{{type}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>estimated total:</td>
    <td>${{total}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>what</td>
    <td>{{what}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>how many</td>
    <td>{{count}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>when:</td>
    <td style="word-wrap: break-word;
               width: 300px;">{{date_from}} to {{date_to}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>who:</td>
    <td style="color:#FF8D58;">{{name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then, if you were to provide the following data to the template...

```
let data = [
    {
        id: 123, // A "key" for the user to have a way to reference the data
        name: "Mike",
        type: "availability check request",
        total: 250.00,
        what: "Radio",
        count: 2,
        date_from: new Date(3-28-2018),
        date_to: new Date(3-30-2018)
    }
];
```

... the table similar to the one you provided would result after processing the template.

This is obviously very generalized and can't be applied to every scenario, but should answer your question. Feel free to update your post, or comment, with more information and I will try to update to match your example.

---

#### *Edit:*

In order to achieve the same with Laravel Blade, we will have to create a `[FILE NAME].blade.php` file. This will be the file that contains our template. Laravel has quite a bit of documentation relating to syntax on [their Templates page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates). This should be a rough translation of the previous template.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>type:</td>
    <td>{{ $type }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>estimated total:</td>
    <td>${{ $total }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>what</td>
    <td>{{ $what }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>how many</td>
    <td>{{ $count }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>when:</td>
    <td style="word-wrap: break-word;
               width: 300px;">{{ date("F j/s @ g:ia", $dateFrom) }} to {{ date("F j/s @ g:ia", $dateTo) }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>who:</td>
    <td style="color:#FF8D58;">{{ $name }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `{{ date("F j/s @ g:ia", $date) }}` function takes a given timestamp and formats it to the given format. The documentation can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), but simply:

- F: **March** 28/18 @ 7:00pm
- j: March **28**/18 @ 7:00pm
- s: March 28/**18** @ 7:00pm
- g: March 28/18 @ **7**:00pm
- i: March 28/18 @ 7:**00**pm
- a: March 28/18 @ 7:00**pm**

Comment: Can you explain about this `{{ date("F j/s @ g:ia", $date) }}`  ?

Comment: I'll add it to the post. In the mean time, the documentation for the php date() function can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: @user5447339 My apologies, I didn't see that you had both a to *and* from date. I've updated the post in each related section and it should be more clear now.

Comment: I have accepted your answer.  I am wondering if you have any experience in html email. I have one similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51049028/does-padding-works-in-html-email) related to html email.  I am wondering if you can have a look on it.

Comment: I am wondering if you we can use padding for html email. Will it for outlook ?

Comment: I took a look, but I don't have much experience in Outlook. Sorry about that!

Comment: Actually the date and time are not fixed so can we use {{$date_from}} , {{$date_to}} ?

Comment: That would work too, you would just have to do the formatting prior to inserting into the template.